# Menu Bar Overlapping Site

Tags: css, menu, overlapping

Im trying to make a cool portfolio site, but cant seem to get a cool menu-bar. Now i came by this menu-bar. It are 3 stripes in the top-right corner and when pressed the menu comes in front of the website. I find this one of the coolest menu bars ive seen in a while. Im talking about this one:

[image]

I hope someone can help me out how to achieve this or knows a site thats got a similar plugin.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can you share your code or what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [fullscreen overlay menu](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/06/fullscreen-overlay-effects/).